# auto complete for the rest of the text

Tags: php, database, autocomplete, insert, strlen

im making a posting script little like twitter

how ever im making the posting text to be 100 Characters only.

now i wanna make something like 
when user write about 50 Characters 
there will be another 50 Characters empty

i want a php method to fill the rest of the text with dots (.)

like this

the user post is:

hello my name is Youssef Subehi

in database i want it to be :

hello my name is Youssef Subehi ...... dots to be 100 Characters

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please post your current code so we can see what it's doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str_pad($myString, 100 ,'.',STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

Should work for you.

It will fill the string with dots. till the length is 100